# With match_parent why is the text going below the view on the right?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I am not sure I understand how `match_parent` works.
Example I am confused:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/text1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="I expected this really long text to wrap around since the space on the right is already occupied but it goes bellow the red view"
                        />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/text1"
                    android:text="Bla"
                    />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            >
            <View
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:background="@color/red"
            />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This results in the following:
[image]

So the text extends to the parent's width but under the red view.
If I remove the view the text which is very long wraps around to the next line.

So my question is why isn't the red view "detected" so that the text would wrap to the next line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the `match_parent` of the `TextView`, but the `fill_parent` of the linear layout:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

This will make it as wide as its parent, which in this case is the entire screen. You could try to add `android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/theOtherLinearLayout"`.

Another option is to use a *horizontal* LinearLayout to keep the text view from going under the red box. You can use

```
 android:layout_width="0dp"
 android:layout_weight="1"
```

to indicate that a view should use **all** remaining space in this layout (after the fixed elements, in this case the red box, have been positioned).

Comment: The `layout_toLeft` of the view solved it!!!! I can not set `layout_weight="0dp"` and  `layout_weight="1"`. Android Studio does not allow them as an option for this layout for some reason (I assume in your answer you meant weight and not height as 0)

Comment: OK, great. I meant *width* instead of *height*. This would only work inside a LinearLayout, not inside a RelativeLayout. That's why Android Studio doesn't allow that.

Comment: But how is the layout to the left actually fixing this? I am not clear on the logic

Comment: Within a RelativeLayout, all elements are positioned independently of each other, *unless* you specify otherwise. Without the `toLeftOf`, the linear layout just consumes as much space as available (because you tell it to do so).

Answer (score 1):

RelativeLayout effectively has a z axis, if views are aligned in a way that means their edges are aligned against the same plane then the views added later in the layout are on top of the earlier ones (layered) rather than pushing aside existing content. This means your red square is above/overlaps the textview rather than being besides it.

It's not your question but there is also no need to be nesting your layouts like that either, or wrapping individual views in their own layouts. It's really inefficient to write and to render. You can learn about the differences in layouts and when to use them from the developer tutorials.

I think the following is what you need:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <View android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/shape1"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@color/red"
    />

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/shape1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="I expected this really long text to wrap around since the space on the right is already occupied but it goes bellow the red view"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/text1"
            android:text="Bla"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

To explain those changes/why you dont need the nesting:

- You dont need the outermost LinearLayout becasue it only has one child
- You dont need the LinearLayout around the red square for the same reason, just move android:layout_alignParentRight="true" onto the red square view
- You dont need the LinearLayout around the RelativeLayout that contains hte TextViews for the same reason. move the android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" onto the RelativeLayout child
- You can then stop the red square overlapping the text by making sure it is toRightOf the child RelativeLayout or that the child RelativeLayout ends toLeftOf the red square like my example.
- If you want to improve further you can remove the child RelativeLayout and put the toLeftOf and android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" on the first TextView and android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/text1" plus android:layout_alignRight="@+id/text1" on the second TextView and you'll still end up with the same result

Comment: So the problem is the relative's layout width? 1) I thought that the relative layout honors the children's width. If I set the textview's width to wrap_content there is no improvement 2) Is relative layout similar to frame layout then? 3) How can I fix this? Setting the relative's layout to wrap_content also does not solve this

Comment: A relative layout positions views relative to eachother. A linear layout arranges them linearly. A frame layout should frame one thing.

Comment: But how can I fix this? I am using this layout approach because it solves me another problem I have. I have only problem in long strings now